# Groovy script to merge xml nodes depending on a node value in the incoming payload

Tags: xml, groovy

I am receiving a payload of employees timesheet with multiple weeks attendance, need to merge the multiple weeks entries into one entry based on employee id and send it to receiver system.

I have added the current and expected payloads.

Thanks in Advance.

The following is the current payload with multiple weeks entries of 1049. Now i need to check if there are multiple entries for any e.id in this case 1049 and merge all the entries in to one with latest  in this case 2023-07-18T06:52:23.000 and send it.

Current Payload

```
  <EmployeeTimeSheet>
  <EmployeeTimeSheet>
    <approvalStatus>APPROVED</approvalStatus>
    <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-18T06:51:27.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
    <employeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-06-18T05:14:39.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>2:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>P</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T10:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-06-13T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
    </employeeTimeSheetEntry>
    <userId>1049</userId>
  </EmployeeTimeSheet>
  <EmployeeTimeSheet>
    <approvalStatus>APPROVED</approvalStatus>
    <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-18T06:51:42.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
    <employeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-04T07:07:34.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>1:50</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>P</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T09:50:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-04T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
    </employeeTimeSheetEntry>
    <userId>1004</userId>
  </EmployeeTimeSheet>
  <EmployeeTimeSheet>
    <approvalStatus>APPROVED</approvalStatus>
    <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-18T06:51:46.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
    <employeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-02T06:37:26.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-06-20T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-02T06:38:02.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-06-21T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-02T06:38:35.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-06-22T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
    </employeeTimeSheetEntry>
    <userId>1049</userId>
  </EmployeeTimeSheet>
    <EmployeeTimeSheet>
    <approvalStatus>APPROVED</approvalStatus>
    <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-18T06:51:57.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
    <employeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-03T08:10:47.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-02T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-03T08:11:39.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-03T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
    </employeeTimeSheetEntry>
    <userId>1049</userId>
  </EmployeeTimeSheet>
  <EmployeeTimeSheet>
    <approvalStatus>APPROVED</approvalStatus>
    <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-18T06:52:23.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
    <employeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-11T14:39:06.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-11T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-13T11:22:05.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-13T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
    </employeeTimeSheetEntry>
    <userId>1049</userId>
  </EmployeeTimeSheet>
  <EmployeeTimeSheet>
    <approvalStatus>APPROVED</approvalStatus>
    <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-18T06:42:23.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
    <employeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-11T11:45:49.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-09T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-11T11:46:38.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-10T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-11T11:52:34.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>2:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>o</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T19:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-10T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
    </employeeTimeSheetEntry>
    <userId>1079</userId>
  </EmployeeTimeSheet>
  </EmployeeTimeSheet>
```

Expected output payload

```
  <EmployeeTimeSheet>
  <EmployeeTimeSheet>
    <approvalStatus>APPROVED</approvalStatus>
    <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-18T06:51:42.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
    <employeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-04T07:07:34.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>1:50</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>P</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T09:50:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-04T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
    </employeeTimeSheetEntry>
    <userId>1004</userId>
  </EmployeeTimeSheet>
  <EmployeeTimeSheet>
    <approvalStatus>APPROVED</approvalStatus>
    <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-18T06:52:23.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
    <employeeTimeSheetEntry>
    <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-06-18T05:14:39.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>2:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>P</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T10:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-06-13T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-02T06:37:26.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-06-20T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-02T06:38:02.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-06-21T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-02T06:38:35.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-06-22T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-03T08:10:47.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-02T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-03T08:11:39.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-03T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-11T14:39:06.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-11T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-13T11:22:05.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-13T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
    </employeeTimeSheetEntry>
    <userId>1049</userId>
  </EmployeeTimeSheet>
  <EmployeeTimeSheet>
    <approvalStatus>APPROVED</approvalStatus>
    <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-18T06:42:23.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
    <employeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-11T11:45:49.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-09T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-11T11:46:38.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>9:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T08:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>MD</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-10T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <lastModifiedDateTime>2023-07-11T11:52:34.000</lastModifiedDateTime>
        <quantityInHoursAndMinutes>2:00</quantityInHoursAndMinutes>
        <startTime>1970-01-01T17:00:00.000</startTime>
        <timeTypeName>o</timeTypeName>
        <endTime>1970-01-01T19:00:00.000</endTime>
        <startDate>2023-07-10T00:00:00.000</startDate>
      </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
    </employeeTimeSheetEntry>
    <userId>1079</userId>
  </EmployeeTimeSheet>
  </EmployeeTimeSheet>
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Sorry @cfrick  I am looking for the code. I haven't tried.

Comment: SO is not a offshore coding service; right now it's unclear where you
are struggling.  Reading the XML? Grouping (use `.groupBy()`? Moving the
nodes around? Writing the XML back?